# ngAnimated on nghide doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/cPyi8lukckyo9EFReI9V?p=preview

The delete fade away but not when I click on the checkbox, any idea where I've gone wrong?

```
    <li class="task" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-hide="task.done">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done">
{{task.name}}
<button ng-click="del($index)">del</button>
</li>
```

css

```
.task.ng-enter,
.task.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.25s linear all;
  transition:0.25s linear all;
  opacity:0;

}
.task.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.task.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.task.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.25s linear all;
  transition:0.25s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}
.task.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to include the ng-hide class in your animations
take a look at this, this is in case you want just to hide the tasks and not delete them

http://plnkr.co/edit/xrKfNqaTxNL6xw1NBAkO?p=preview

i forked your example into this
using ng-hide ng-hide-add

Comment: ng-hide is hide but what is ng-hide-add??

Comment: ng-hide-add is the transitional class for hiding elements. every class based action on angular has its transitioanl state classes, same as entre and leave there are add and remove which can also have the -active tail.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are only hiding it, not removing it.

You will need to use `ng-if` in this case:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li class="task" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="!task.done">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done">
        {{task.name}}
        <button ng-click="del($index)">del</button>
    </li>
</body>
```

[Here's your demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GU0Lu5Fx8kMOeDKmBwmw?p=preview)

**EDIT** OP was looking for checkbox to apply a strike through, pause, then fade out.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li class="task" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-hide="task.done" ng-class="(task.done)?'strike':''">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done">
        {{task.name}}
        <button ng-click="del($index)">del</button>
    </li>
</body>
```

Added following CSS:

```
.task.ng-hide {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear all;
  transition: 0.25s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.task.ng-hide-add {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  display: block !important;
}

.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

[Demo v2](http://plnkr.co/edit/0mmYbsYDHRPK4GOmLf1O?p=preview)

Comment: I can't apply strike css with this, I tried nng-class="{'taskdone-true':task.done}", i just fade away

Comment: What do you want to happen on check?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're after? http://plnkr.co/edit/d9K6YQqci2ieILAdRhNr?p=preview

Comment: I want when it's checked, it strike the text and slowly fade down, possible?

Comment: @user3522722 Here you go, I'll update my answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/0mmYbsYDHRPK4GOmLf1O?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Toggling checkbox just make item hidden. But `del()` function remove item from scope.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `ng-hide="task.done"` from  `<li>` and use `ng-if="!task.done"`

Check this out

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5srAX1Fgmnm45z4mP6D?p=preview)**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li class="task" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="!task.done">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done">{{task.name}}
        <button ng-click="del($index)">del</button>
    </li>
</body>
```

Comment: if I do so, my ng-class="{'taskdone-true':task.done==1}" will not work.

Comment: where is this ng-class="{'taskdone-true':task.done==1}"  in your code